# android set multiple alarms simultaneosuly

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Ok, let me modify the question and make it much easier. I Hope you'll be able to get me the solution for this. Both the alarms should be scheduled simultaneously, which is not happening here. I am even using unique requestcode for the pending intent. **HELP ME please.....**

> //On click Listener

```
private OnClickListener mOneShotListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmController.this, OneShotAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this,0, intent, 0);
        //I even tried sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this,0, intent, PendinIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        //the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

        // Schedule the alarm!

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

        //adds 2 minutes to the time

        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

        sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this,1, intent,0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender2);
    }
};
```

**OLD Question:**
I want to set two alarms at the same time for two different operations to be performed.

For Eg. A user sets alarm at 2'O clock and sets the duration to 15 mins. The first alarm should fire at 2'O clock which performs function1 and the second alarm should fire at 2:15 as the user specified the duration as 15 mins which performs the function2. This operation should be repeated everyday at 2'O clock unless the user changes the time.

I am calling this both functions on button click:

> On Click Event

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View view) {  
        ..........  
        ..........  
        new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(mRowId, mCalendar);  
        new ReminderManager(this).wakeReminder(mRowId, mCalendar, duration);  
        }  
    }
```

The setReminder contains

> //sets alarm at 2'O clock

```
public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when, String duration){  
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId);    
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,(int)System.currentTimeMillis(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);    
}
```

The wakeReminder contains

> //adds duration i.e. 15mins

```
public void wakeReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when, String duration){
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiverWake.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId);
        Long d = Long.parseLong(duration);
        Long mins = d*60*100; 
        Long milli = when.getTimeInMillis() + mins;
        PendingIntent  pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milli, pi);
}
```

I have noticed that whenever `mAlarmManager.set();` is executed successfully the `LogCat` shows  notification like
`"enqueueToast pkg=com.jellboi.android.togglemode callback=android.app ITransientNotification$stub$proxy@43c0c5f8 duration=0"`

but when I set both the alarms simultaneously  the notification is not shown when the `mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);` is executed
but the notification is shown when `mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milli, pi);` is executed. Also the notification is set for the original time i.e. 2'O clock and not after adding 15mins to it's duration.

Please help, I tried a lot of ways to call this functions at different places like after the 1st alarm is fired but all in vain.

Comment: It may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649402/alarm-manager-scheduling-multiple-non-repeating-events

Answer (score 10):

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this,0, intent, 0);
```

You have problem in this line. If you want to simultaneously fire two alarma then you should do something like this

```
PendingIntent sender =       PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmController.this,giveUniqueRequestIdsHere, intent, 0);
```

Comment: can you post code of geting pending intent in broadcast manager in which we can fire two diffrent task at same time ..

Comment: Nice answer, Save my time

Answer (score 4):

```
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Do the same for your PendingIntent.getActivity();

Answer (score 2):

Hi try using this to generate request I was generating my own request code but this line worked for me

```
final int intent_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

When launch new OneShotAlarm.class, it have to design launch mode. Default setting would ignore the second time launch, if the first instance still existed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmController.this, OneShotAlarm.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you forgot to set "sender2" before your second call.

you change the value of sender, then put sender2 as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of your task in the Service class and set the array in the for loop, inside the for loop you can call your task simultaneously at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
Date date = cal.getTime();
cal.clear();

Cursor c = database.query(mArray.get(mPosition), new String[]{"days"},"days"+"!="+0, null, null, null, null);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,date.getMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date.getDate());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(nextScreen.this, AlaramReciver.class);
i.putExtra("Start",mArray.get(mPosition));

Editor medit = getSharedPreferences("Start", 0).edit();
medit.putString("Start", mArray.get(mPosition));medit.commit();

PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,mPosition, i, 0);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);
```

You have set to the time like this, and once you set time in alarm manager it will automatically call the functions daily. Use different request code for `pendingintent`.

If you want call second function. You just add the time in 15 min in the

```
cal.set(Calender.MINUTE,min+15);
```

Comment: Hi,Yi Jiang thanks for the reply,I am setting my time correctly an the alarm fire perfectly at the specified time as I specified in my code.I've just omitted my code where I am specifying the time. The problem which I am not able to solve is, I am setting the two alarms simultaneously,eg.first at 2'O clock and other at 2:15 at the same time as soon as I click the save button. Now only 1 alarm is fired, i.e. the first one at 2'O clock, the other one doesn't nor it shows any error.When I debugged,the logCat shows dat only 1 alarm is queued and not the other one & m using currentSystemTime for pi